# dask call graph: missing required positional argument

Tags: python, dask

I would like to have downstream functions in a dask call graph take multiple arguments, but when I call `get`, `dask` says I am missing positional arguments.

Here is a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex) :

```
>>> import dask.threaded
>>> dsk = {'in':2, 'f1': (lambda x:(x**2, x**3), 'in'), 'out':(lambda x2,x3:(x2,x3), 'f1')}
>>> dask.threaded.get(dsk, 'out')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/nathan/GLOBAL/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/threaded.py", line 76, in get
    pack_exception=pack_exception, **kwargs)
  File "/home/nathan/GLOBAL/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/local.py", line 462, in get_async
    raise_exception(exc, tb)
  File "/home/nathan/GLOBAL/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/compatibility.py", line 112, in reraise
    raise exc
  File "/home/nathan/GLOBAL/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/local.py", line 230, in execute_task
    result = _execute_task(task, data)
  File "/home/nathan/GLOBAL/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/core.py", line 119, in _execute_task
    return func(*args2)
TypeError: <lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x3'
```

How can I have a function take multiple arguments without using `*args`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output `(x**2, x**3)` is a single `tuple` which won't be automatically unpacked; just like it won't if you pass a single `tuple` to a function with multiple parameters.

But, if you don't like `*args`, one thing you could do would be to unpack the tuple explicitly:

```py
In [21]: def out(x):
    ...:     x2, x3 = x
    ...:     return (x2, 3*x3)
    ...:

In [22]: dsk = {'in': 2, 'f1': (lambda x:(x**2, x**3), 'in'), 'out': (out, 'f1')}

In [23]: dask.threaded.get(dsk, 'out')
Out[23]: (4, 24)
```

Or, if you don't mind just accessing the elements by index:

```py
In [27]: dsk = {'in': 2, 'f1': (lambda x: (x**2, x**3), 'in'), 'out': (lambda x: (x[0], 3*x[1]), 'f1')}

In [29]: dask.threaded.get(dsk, 'out')
Out[29]: (4, 24)
```

Comment: Although I dont like it, from my experiments earlier in the day, this is the answer. thank you, fuglede